# Visualizing top expressed genes

Tags: r, differential-expression, deseq2

I have a spreadsheet of CPM values

I want to visualize the top 20 genes expressed across my samples

This is how my data look like

```
> head(b[1:5,1:5])
                 30566-001 - CPM 30566-002 - CPM 30566-003 - CPM 30566-004 - CPM 30566-005 - CPM
hsa-miR-548ap-3p               0               0               0               0               0
hsa-miR-548t-3p                0               0               0               0               0
hsa-miR-548e-3p                0               0               0               0               0
hsa-miR-548az-3p               0               0               0               0               0
hsa-miR-548f-3p                0               0               0               0               0
> dim(b)
[1] 2632   42
>
```

How I can do that?

Comment: Just make a heatmap?

Comment: Then from a data frame with 2632 genes, how I select a list of genes for heatmap? Because a heatmap with 2632 genes is not clear while my main purpose is to shows a list of highly expressed genes across my samples

Comment: select the N genes with the highest average expression across all samples?

Answer (score 2):

Gene selection is entirely on you and on the question you ask. Most expressed genes would be selected by `rowMeans` or `rowMedians` or even `rowSums` but this is not very informative as digital expression levels (=counts) is influenced by many technical factors and there is (to my knowledge) no direct link to biological relevance.

Alternatively, you can select by genes that vary a lot between experimental groups. Naively that could be the rowwise variance (`rowVars`) or standard deviation of the logCPMs (use logscale, otherwise variance is a function of the expression level) or the output of a differential analysis. Ideally plug the raw counts into DESeq2 or similar frameworks. If you only have CPMs then you probably want to feed the logCPMs into limma-trend pipeline, see for a discussion on ways to get going with normalized counts for differential expression in this [Bioconductor thread](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/125144/#125156).

Visualization is then again on you. Either make a heatmap (see for example ComplexHeatmap package) or aggregate the genes into a PCA (see for example PCAtools package at Bioconductor), all mentioned packages contain extensive example code and background information which is fully sufficient to run such an analysis.